# Glassfish won't start from Intellij unless I run Intellij with sudo

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish, sudo

Title says it all... just trying to get glassfish up and going. This is the error I get

```
Detected server admin port: 4848
[2015-04-06 07:37:56,138] Artifact java_web_app:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server http port: 8080
Command start-domain failed.
JVM failed to start: com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherException: The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

This subcommand requires root privileges: bsexec
```

Surely there's a way around this? I don't really want to run Intellij with sudo every time.

Comment: In Mac, I run the command with sudo: `sudo asadmin start-domain` and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

Answer: GlassFish 4.1, IntelliJ IDEA 14.1

I have no idea (pun not intended) why GlassFish requires a root user account.

You need to execute something like this:

```
/Library/opt/payara-4.1.151/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose=true  domain1
```

Go Run -> Edit Configuration -> Select configuration (acme-payara-project) -> Start Up Configuration

Edit the Startup Script and change it to add the `--verbose-true` parameter.

Comment: FYI, there is now an open issue to get the fix into Payara: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/262

Answer (score 6):

Is this a problem happening on Mac OSX 10.10.3?
If so, we were able to workaround the problem by changing the content of the file `/usr/libexec/StartupItemContext` to

```
#!/bin/sh
unset LAUNCHD_SOCKET
$@
```

We've also reported this workaround on the corresponding glassfish-issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21343

Note that this will only work for glassfish 4.0. In 4.1 they changed the startup code, so this `StartupItemContext` file will no longer be used.

If your glassfish Version is 4.1, the only known workaround at the moment is to start glassfish with the `--verbose=true` param.

Comment: Thx for your comment - but I don't have this file in my /usr/libexec/ folder? How do I create it? Is this all I need to do?

Comment: If your glassfish version is not 4.1, this is all you need to do. If your glassfish version is 4.1, this might not work. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: yeah, that will work. But do you really want to run the app server with root privileges?

Comment: How do change the Edit Configuration in IntelliJ though to add this --verbose=true command? I was looking for the correct Field to add this argument.

Comment: Never mind, blind as a bat.  I will add Answer: GlassFish 4.1 workaround

Comment: --verbose worked for me on Intellij 14.1.4 and osx 10.10.3

Answer (score 5):

Solved this on OS X 10.10.4, IntelliJ 14.1.4 by adding `-v` to the startup script.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Changing the Startup command in the Run Configuration under the "StartUp/Connection" tab to the following worked for me:

```
.../glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose domain1
```